# Android Navigation Tab Layout

Tags: android, layout, tabs, navigation

I create a custom view for navigation tab. It is Ok. However, there are 2 problems with this layout: the icon appears a little above the center position and the text overlays the navigation indicator. The navigation tab looks like this:
[image]

Here is my custom layout xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_tab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `android:padding` attribute.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.